# MFC Combobox Add A-Z Drives?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a MFC Combobox i want to add A-Z drives to my combox at runtime 
Currently i am adding like this

```
m_cmbdrive.AddString("A:"); 
    m_cmbdrive.AddString("B:"); 
    m_cmbdrive.AddString("C:")
```

upto

```
m_cmbdrive.AddString("Z:");
```

But it seems not to be gud approach .
Any modularlize code if any body can help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char drive[3];
drive[1]=':';
drive[2]='\0';
for (drive[0]='A';drive[0]<='Z';drive[0]++)
{
     m_cmbdrive.AddString(drive);
}
```

Of course, you should check if drive is available at all before adding it into the combo, et cetera.

Comment: I would use GetLogicalDrives or GetLogicalDriveStrings.